# Function parameter 'was not declared in this scope' in the header file

Tags: c++, scope, header-files

I have a problem with declaring a function in one of my header files (C++), this is how the file looks:

```
#ifndef MACTRANSFERINCLUDE
#define MACTRANSFERINCLUDE
#ifdef USE_MAC

#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

boost::shared_ptr<wstring> browseFolder();
boost::shared_ptr<vector<wstring>> getFilesInDirRecursiveImplementation(boost::shared_ptr<vector<wstring>> dirs, boost::shared_ptr<vector<wstring>> files);

#endif
#endif
```

When building the project (for Mac OSX in XCode), I get "'dirs' was not declared in this scope".

If I also declare a function

```
boost::shared_ptr<vector<wstring>> foo();
```

I get the error "A function call cannot appear in a constant-expression". I'm not very familiar with C++, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And you do include `<vector>` before including your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include header `<vector>`

```
#include <vector>
```

Maybe it is the reason of the error.

I do not see a big difference between declaration

```
boost::shared_ptr<wstring> browseFolder();
```

and

```
boost::shared_ptr<vector<wstring>> foo();
```

So the compiler should issue error

> "A function call cannot appear in a constant-expression".

also for the first declaration.

The only difference is that the second declaration is used `vector` that was not declared. At least it is not seen where it is declared in your header.

Also it is a bad idea to use directive

```
using namespace std;
```

I would remove it and write

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::wstring> browseFolder();

boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::wstring>> getFilesInDirRecursiveImplementation(boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::wstring>> dirs, boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::wstring>> files);
```

The other reason is that maybe you need to insert a blank between symbols `>>` For example

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::wstring> > dirs
```

It seems indeed that you have an old compiler that does not use the new syntax for the pair of symbols `>>` in template argument declarations. So you have to insert a blank between these two symbols `> >`

Comment: I added it to the header (as you're right it should be included) but unfortunately it's still the same problem.

Edit:

 vector<wstring<> bar();

works fine though.

Comment: I changed it like you said but the problem persists. I tried declaring a function std::vector<wstring> bar(); and it works fine, so there maybe is something wrong with the way I use boost::shared_ptr?

Comment: @user3351083  I have appended my post. See it again.